# How do I click a specific location in an active application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently using LockBitmap to find locations in my application that I want to click. Everything works wonderfully until I click a button that brings up a child window within the application. Using lockbitmap here has no effect. Its as if it is only able to see the main application screen (which is now in the background.)

Since I'm unable to use lockbitmap to find the image and click the location I want, I'm trying to hard code the click location. However, its not clicking the right location. Im worried that it might be clicking outside of my application window. I've used Paint after snipping an image of the entire application window and found the location of the Continue Button to be at 330,430. Thoughts?

Summary-
Working in Visual Studio's 2019, Windows Form App using .Net framework Im trying to automate the process of clicking a button that opens a child window in the main application. Since LockBits/LockBitmap is not able to distinguish between the two windows I'm trying to hard code in a "move mouse to button X-location and click". However, when I added the coordinates, nothing happens.

Currently my code is-

```
private void RunClickContinue()

{          
var handle = GetWindowsHandle();
var topleft = GetProcessWindowPoint(handle);
var clickpoint = new Point(topleft.X + 330, topleft.Y + 430);
User32.SetCursorPos(clickpoint.X, clickpoint.Y);
User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Thread.Sleep(50);
User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

As for my previously attempt using LockBitmap:

```
    private LockBitmap ClickContinue;

    private bool RunClickContinue()
    {
    if (!LockedImageSearch.DoesImageExist(screenshot, ClickContinue))
    {
        return false;
    }
    var location = screenshot.GetFirstLocation(ClickContinue);

    if (location != Point.Empty)
    {
        var topleft = GetProcessWindowPoint(handle);
        var clickpoint = new Point(topleft.X + location.X, topleft.Y + location.Y);
        User32.SetCursorPos(clickpoint.X, clickpoint.Y);
        User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What UI Framework are you using (I'm guessing Windows Forms, but I barely recognize any code). What are you trying to achieve (not "what are you doing", but, what do you really want when you are finished). You may want to include a link to some documentation on `LockBitmap`

Comment: Sorry, Im working in Visual Studio's 2019, Windows Form App using .Net framework

Im trying to automate the process of clicking a button that is a child object of the main application window. Since LockBits/LockBitmap is not able to distinguish between the two windows I was trying to hard code in a "move mouse to button and click it" function. However, when I added (what I thought to be) the coordinates, nothing happens and the script does not click the button.

Comment: You should add that info to your question (you can press the `[edit]` button). Also tag your question with the WinForms tsg